# Will this motor driver work with a lower voltage?

Tags: power-supply, motor, h-bridge

I just started studying electrical engineering as a hobby, so I'm a noob.

I'm making a schematic for a sumo robot and I'm using a [L6206](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6206.pdf) dual full-bridge driver to control the two brushed motors. In the data sheet, it says that the power voltage supply can go from 8 to 52 V.

I'm using a [7.6 V battery](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000409147702.html) and a 3.3 V linear regulator.

How can I supply the driver? Will it work with 3.3 V?

I'm sorry if that's a stupid question but I'm really a beginner.

Comment: No, it will not work at 3.3V. You need a step-up supply to drive the driver from a 7.6V battery. Also take into account that the battery voltage drops as it is being used.

Comment: Links not working. Formating

Comment: You need at least 8V for the power supply to the IC, so no. Its logic inputs will accept 3.3 V logic, though.

Comment: It has a low voltage shut down that will prevent it from working correctly with a 7.6 V battery. So no, it won't work. Find another part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, it will not work because of the rated voltage of the L6206 chip.

As a possible solution use a chip rated for voltages from ~ 5V up, or build it as a discrete circuit using some transistors or MOSFETs.

A good simple chip would be a [DRV8833](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8833.pdf?ts=1643019566710&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.be%252F)

It supports 3.3V logic levels on the inputs.
Connect the Driver directly to the battery.

And please use some Battery protection to not destroy your battery in the process of designing your circuit.

Have fun :)